# Is there some server performance issue when forcing download of big files (500mb+) with php?

Tags: php

I've used this method to force download only with small files, but i need to know if i can do it with big files without any server performance problems?

thanks guys.

Comment: What method is `this method`?

Comment: Forcing download via headers...

Comment: http is not a great protocol for file transfer, ftp is better.

Answer (score 2):

Install [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (or whatever equivalent your web server uses) and your problem goes away.